# How do I use NSNotification for subclasses GCRetractableSectionController as there is no viewDidLoad or other such methods

Tags: ios, objective-c

The GCRetractableSectionController is based on NSObject and I have no clue how to implement my idea. Now where should I add observer for notification? Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code showing a handler for notification but I don't know where to listen for the notification.

```
#import "MyRetractableCustomSectionController.h"

#import "CustomCell.h"


@interface BedroomsCustomSectionController()

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray* content;

@end

@implementation BedroomsCustomSectionController
{
NSString * tester;

}
@synthesize content;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Simple subclass

- (NSString *)title {
return NSLocalizedString(@"Bedrooms",);
}

- (NSUInteger)contentNumberOfRow {
return [self.content count];
}

- (NSString *)titleContentForRow:(NSUInteger)row {
return [self.content objectAtIndex:row];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Customization

- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRow:(NSUInteger)row
{
    //All cells in the GCRetractableSectionController will be     indented
  HarrisTableViewCell* cell = (HarrisTableViewCell*)[super cellForRow:row];

cell.indentationLevel = 1;

return cell;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)titleCell {
//I removed the detail text here, but you can do whatever you want
HarrisTableViewCell* titleCell = (HarrisTableViewCell*)[super titleCell];

titleCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"1";
titleCell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

return titleCell;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)contentCellForRow:(NSUInteger)row {
//You can reuse GCRetractableSectionController work by calling super, but you can start from scratch and give a new cell

CustomCellForBedsBaths* contentCell = (CustomCellForBedsBaths*)[super contentCellForRow:row];
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellForBedsBaths" owner:self options:nil];
contentCell = (CustomCellForBedsBaths *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];

 HarrisTableViewCell* titleCell = (HarrisTableViewCell*)[super titleCell];
 if (tester != nil) {
    titleCell.detailTextLabel.text = tester;
 }
 else
 {
 titleCell.detailTextLabel.text = contentCell.labelToShowNumber.text;
 }
 return contentCell;
}


-(void)handleUpdatedData:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"recieved");
[self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Getters

- (NSArray *)content {
if (content == nil) {
    content = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"You can do", nil];
}
return content;
}


@end
// this is the GCRetractableSectionController class :
//
//  GCRetractableSectionController.h
//  Mtl mobile
//
//  Created by Guillaume Campagna on 09-10-19.
//  Copyright 2009 LittleKiwi. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GCRetractableSectionController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isOpen) BOOL open;

- (id) initWithViewController:(UIViewController*) givenViewController;

//Used by the UITableView's dataSource
- (UITableViewCell*) cellForRow:(NSUInteger) row;
- (UITableViewCell *) heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger numberOfRow;

//Customize appearance
//Use only white images if the cells background is dark
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isOnlyUsingWhiteImages) BOOL useOnlyWhiteImages;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIColor* titleTextColor; //nil by default, black text
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIColor* titleAlternativeTextColor; //nil     by default, dark blue
@property (nonatomic, assign) UITableViewRowAnimation rowAnimation;          //Animation to insert/remove cells, UITableViewRowAnimationTop by default

//Must be subclassed to work properly
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString* title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger contentNumberOfRow;
- (NSString*) titleContentForRow:(NSUInteger) row;

//Can be subclassed for more control
- (UITableViewCell*) titleCell;
- (UITableViewCell*) contentCellForRow:(NSUInteger) row;
//Respond to cell selection
- (void) didSelectCellAtRow:(NSUInteger) row;
- (void) didSelectTitleCell;
- (void) didSelectContentCellAtRow:(NSUInteger) row;

//Reserved for subclasses
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

Comment: What notifications you want?

Comment: i want to update a label on main expandable row based on selected value from expanded child rows

Comment: @tiny sunlight if u could fix the issue instead...

Comment: I don't know anything about ios!